# Matlab. How do I import a folder into the workspace?

Tags: matlab

I want to load a folder of .mat files into the workspace of Matlab so that I don't need to manually load them one by one...

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend the following: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/10867-uipickfiles--uigetfile-on-steroids

This tool enables you to select not only one folder, but also multiple folders/files in different directories.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this to import all files in a folder and be able to cycle through them.

```
function FileCycle

PathSets = 'P:\MAL Archive\Movies\2014_09_30\';
List = dir([PathSets '*.mp4']);

clear f;
for i = 1:length(List)
clear S;
load([PathSets List(i).name]);
f(i)= S;
end
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `addpath(folderName)` function to add the folder you want to the top of the search path, this should give you access to whatever .mat files are in the included folder. To learn the syntax `help addpath` in matlab should give you all you need to know.

Comment: Adding a path to the search path doesn't solve the problem.  They need to also import the MAT files too into the workspace.  You've probably only made it slightly easier to do the work.